# Retrieve DB values and display in humantask in jbpm?

Tags: jbpm

How we can display DB values into humantask form.

Explanation: When a user selects a id, the corresponding DB row should get populated in the humantask variables?

With the help of handlers, i could able to insert the values in to DB, but I'm unable to retrieve the values from DB and display in humantask.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom node ,in this node you can call a webservice(SOAP) which retrieve your data from database ,and pass this data to the humantask as variable.